# How to move CSS classes to the right html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xsltforms

I trying out some stuff with XSLT and XSLTForms and I get into a peculiar problem. I want to add style to some `xforms:trigger` but the XForms implementation (**XSLTForms**) that I use transforms the following simple xforms code into these html elements:

```
<span id="multiplication" class="btn btn-warning xforms-control xforms-trigger xforms-appearance-minimal">
    <span class="value">
        <button type="button">
            <span id="xsltforms-mainform-label-2_8_6_2_4_3_" class="xforms-label">*</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</span>
```

And here is the actual XForms code.

```
<xf:trigger class="btn btn-warning" id="division">
   <xf:label>/</xf:label>
</xf:trigger>
```

So, when it gets transformed into html elements, the structure is

```
|_span
  |_span
     |_button
       |_span (for the label)
```

So, I want this button to be styled by twitter's bootstrap with css rules for `btn-warning`. But in the final html, the css class `class="btn btn-warning"` is inserted into the first `span` element, which contains a `button` element. So I get sort of two buttons - inside one another ...

Ideally I would like to move the `class="btn btn-warning"` from the `<span> element to the` element, where it should actually belong. What is the best way to achieve that with let's say jQuery?

So the desired result should be:

```
<span id="multiplication" class="xforms-control xforms-trigger xforms-appearance-minimal">
    <span class="value">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
            <span id="xsltforms-mainform-label-2_8_6_2_4_3_" class="xforms-label">*</span>
        </button>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery it's simple:

```
$(function () {
    $("span.btn").each(function () {
        var cssClasses = this.className.split(" "), i;

        for (i = 0; i < cssClasses.length; i++) {
            // remove any class that does not start with "btn" from the array
            if (cssClasses[i].indexOf("btn") === -1) {
                cssClasses.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        cssClasses = cssClasses.join(" ");

        // transfer remaining classes from this to the inner <button>
        $(this)
            .removeClass(cssClasses)
            .find("button").addClass(cssClasses);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure it out!